# animation not working sequentially

Tags: java, android, animation

Hi i am developing an app where i'm using different animations however my problem is animations are getting executed concurrently instead of one_by_one.
To solve that problem i used animation set but still the problem is same.
I dont understand where i'm going wrong.
Please any help would be appreciated Thank you
my code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        Animation animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in);
        Animation expandIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.image_popup);
        Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.slide_in_down);
        background_image = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.background_image);
        background_image.startAnimation(slideIn);
        circleImageView = (CircleImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.circle_image);
        circleImageView.startAnimation(expandIn);
        profile_recyclerview.clearAnimation();
        profile_recyclerview.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
        animationSet.addAnimation(slideIn);
        animationSet.addAnimation(expandIn);
        animationSet.addAnimation(animFadeIn);
        animFadeIn.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ObjectAnimator` and `AnimatorSet` instead of `Animation` and `AnimationSet`
see [Property Animation Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation)